# How to create a regex that will substitute whatever that is following an email signature with an empty string?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to create a regex that will substitute whatever that is following an email signature (begining with the person's name) with an empty string.

I use a PII data as my input, so general examples can be:

1. `xxx best, [NAME] xxx`
2. `xxx best. [NAME] xxx`
3. `xxx best, regards, [NAME] xxx`
4. `xxx best, regards, [NAME]`
5. `xxx regards, [NAME]`
6. `xxx best, regards [NAME]`

I wish my to remove the `[NAME]` pattern and all that is after it, but of course it should only remove it if before it there's one (or more) of the signature patterns (for example: best, or best. or best or regards).

Of course that `best` and `regards` are not the only closing examples, and eac of these can have a few of punctuation postfixes.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Here is what I have so far:

```
text = 'bla bla sincerely, best, [NAME] bli bli.'
text = re.sub(r'((?:thanks(?: again)?(?:\.|,|!)|thanks in advance(?:\.|,|!)|many thanks(?:\.|,|!)|(?:best,)|best regards(?:\.|,|!)?|with best regards|All the best(?:\.|,|!)?|(?:sincerely(?:,|\.))|cheers(?:\.|,|!)|have a nice day(?:\.|,|!)?)\s*)+(\[NAME\].*)', r'\2', text, flags=re.DOTALL|re.UNICODE|re.IGNORECASE)
```

The wrong output is currently:

```
bla bla[NAME] bli bli
```

The desired output is:

```
bla bla sincerely, best,
```

Comment: Some of those signatures look grammatically awkward at best ex: *"best, regards, John Doe"* should be *"best regards, John Doe"*

Comment: Not always. some of my data has this pattern that I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

First, extract the phrases to a dedicated list; this ensures readability and maintainability:

```py
phrases = [
  'thanks',
  'thanks again',
  'thanks in advance',
  'many thanks',
  'best',
  'best regards',
  'with best regards',
  'all the best',
  'sincerely',
  'cheers',
  'have a nice day'
]
```

...then construct the regex from that:

```py
import re

escaped_phrases = '|'.join(re.escape(phrase) for phrase in phrases)
regex = re.compile(
    fr'((?:(?:{escaped_phrases})[.,!]?\s*)+)\[NAME].*',
    flags = re.DOTALL | re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE
)
```

Explanation:

```
(                # Match a capturing group consisting of
  (?:            #    non-capturing groups
    (?:phrases)  #    that has one of the phrases,
    [.,!]?       #    followed by '.', ',' or '!', optionally,
    \s*          #    then 0+ whitespace characters,
  )+             # 1+
)                # then
\[NAME].*        # '[NAME]' literally and anything after that.
```

Since we're matching both the phrases and the name, we need to give the former back with `\1`:

```py
def remove_name(text):
  return regex.sub(r'\1', text)
```

Try it:

```py
text = 'bla bla sincerely, best, [NAME] bli bli.'

print(regex)

'''
re.compile(
  '((?:(?:thanks|thanks again|...)[.,!]?\\s*)+)\\[NAME].*',
  re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE | re.DOTALL
)
'''

text = regex.sub(r'\1', text)
print(text)  # 'bla bla sincerely, best, '
```